# How to make a local "scroll to ID" on post?

Tags: posts, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to figure out the best way to do something similar with http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/
[image]

I understand that I have to use scrollspy and work on couple jQuery line for "scroll-to" thing and also working with affix, I have no problem doing that on static page.

On the post of WordPress, I want to have an "index" where the reader can jump from one section to another (exactly like the getbootstrap page).

What I don't know is how to generate this on the post dynamically, since

- Each post will have a different index name
- Each post will have a different amount of index.
- Each post will have a different id name.

I am looking for using Advance Custom Field.

Anyone has an experience on this or can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would a table of contents plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/table-of-contents-plus/screenshots/ work for your case?

Comment: ?Can you explain a little bit as how it helps

Comment: This is probably a good one, I think the good word to describe what I need is the table-of-contents

Answer (score 0):

```
/* a.page-scroll  is your manu link class */


$('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top()
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I don't think you're reading the question